# WebView on Flutter Web Not working with external library

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

currently I am developing an app using Flutter Web and I've been trying to use this library which does not have a lot of documentation.
I've tried the example provided but for some reason it's not working
In the example there is no  `onLoaded() {}` function method and without that I get an error saying that I have to implement it.
Finally, if I want to set the width and height of the website I should call setState(). How do I do that?

Link to the library https://pub.dev/packages/easy_web_view2

Code: (I'm running main() in another file)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:easy_web_view2/easy_web_view2.dart';

class Quiz extends StatelessWidget {
  const Quiz({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('CyberQuiz'),
      ),
      body: EasyWebView(
        src: 'https://www.ncsc.gov.uk/',
        onLoaded: () {
          print('Loaded!!');
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of an unobvious issue. I was trying to embed a government website. Apparently you are not allowed to do that.
I am also using a different library which is called webviewx. It has better documentation than the other one